# Error: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code."

Tags: support

Where is the mistake?
Question text:

I add two class libraries to the "solution".
I am running debugging.
Chrome starts up.
In Chrome, the start page `\Home\Index.cshtml` appears.
After `~10` seconds, debugging automatically stops.

**Description.**
I created a project - `WebApplCore`;
I added a class library to the solution - `Models`;
I added a class library to the solution - `DBRepository`.

Project "WebApplCore" - ASP.NET Core;
Class Library "Models", "DBRepository" - Net.Standard 2.0.

**Conditional notations for "tests":**
- "+" - `project` is included in the `decision`;
- "-" - `project` is not included in the `decision`.

**Test 1.**
  WebApplCore - "+";
  Models - "+";
  DBRepository - "-".
**Result:** debugging works stably. Turning off debugging does not occur.

**Test 2.**
  WebApplCore - "+";
  Models - "-";
  DBRepository - "+".
**Result:** debugging works stably. Turning off debugging does not occur.

**Test 3. !!!**
  WebApplCore - "+";
  Models - "+";
  DBRepository - "+".
**Result:** debugging does not work stably !!!. After ~10 seconds, debugging automatically stops.

**Question.**
Why in **Test 3.!!!** does debugging turn off?

**Picture-1**
  [image]

**Picture-2**
[image]

**Picture-3**
[image]

**Picture-4**
[image]

**Picture-5**
[image: Picture-5]

Comment: @rene `//` these characters hit by accident.
In the question, I do not have them.
In the current question, `//` I deleted

Comment: Remove all the bolding (**), If you need a heading use `#` (or `###` if you want a smaller heading). Do not use ; after a code block, Do not use multiple symbols (no !!!)

Comment: @rene re: *"Do not use ; after a code block"*, they're being used for list item separation... better would be to recommend using bullets for listing items (at least for what OP is trying to do)

Comment: @Nick sure! Any guess that might solve this mess is welcome. It is a bit hard to reverse engineer a regex by observing its fail cases ...